# Can't update data in datastore Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datastore

I have a function to store a list of string into the datastore in Android

Here is the code:

```
    suspend fun saveLang(context: Context, data: String, langKey: String) {
        val dataStoreKey = stringSetPreferencesKey(langKey)
        val lastValue = readLang(context, langKey)
        if (!lastValue.contains(data)) {
            if (lastValue.size == 3) {
                lastValue.removeAt(0)
            }
            lastValue.add(lastValue.size, data)
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[dataStoreKey] = lastValue.toSet()
            }
        } else {
            lastValue.removeAt(lastValue.indexOf(data))
            lastValue.add(lastValue.size, data)
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[dataStoreKey] = lastValue.toSet()
            }
        }

    }
```

When I call the saveLang() function, if the data does not exist in the datastore, I will remove the first element of the list and add the new data to the end of the list. I want the first value added to be at the start of the list and the latest element to be at the end of the list. If the data already exists in the datastore, I will swap it to the end of the list, but my code doesn't seem to work. When I update data, the datastore will ignore the update if the list has the same element but in a different position.

I have tried this and it works:

```
    suspend fun saveLang(context: Context, data: String, langKey: String) {
        val dataStoreKey = stringSetPreferencesKey(langKey)
        val lastValue = readLang(context, langKey)
        if (!lastValue.contains(data)) {
            if (lastValue.size == 3) {
                lastValue.removeAt(0)
            }
            lastValue.add(lastValue.size, data)
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[dataStoreKey] = lastValue.toSet()
            }
        } else {
            lastValue.removeAt(lastValue.indexOf(data))
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[dataStoreKey] = lastValue.toSet()
            }
            lastValue.add(lastValue.size, data)
            context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
                settings[dataStoreKey] = lastValue.toSet()
            }
        }

    }
```

However, I don't want to store data twice. Is there any better way to achieve my requirement?

Any advice or insight is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is that the data store doesn't update the list if the elements are the same even if the order of the elements has changed and that is exactly what you want to do; change the order.

Here, try this one:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson // add this import

suspend fun saveLang(context: Context, data: String, langKey: String) {
val dataStoreKey = stringPreferencesKey(langKey)
val gson = Gson()

val lastValueJson = context.dataStore.data
    .map { preferences ->
        preferences[dataStoreKey]
    }
    .firstOrNull()

val lastValue = if (lastValueJson != null) {
    gson.fromJson(lastValueJson, MutableList::class.java) as MutableList<String>
} else {
    mutableListOf()
}

if (lastValue.contains(data)) {
    lastValue.remove(data) // Remove existing instance
} else if (lastValue.size == 3) {
    lastValue.removeAt(0) // Remove oldest element if list size exceeds 3
}

lastValue.add(data) // Add the new or updated element to the end

context.dataStore.edit { settings ->
    settings[dataStoreKey] = gson.toJson(lastValue)
}
}
```

This approach uses JSON to serialize and deserialize the list to preserve the order of its elements.
Try it out and get back to me.

Comment: Your code doesn't work the way I expected. I want the latest element added to the list to be at the end of the list. The problem is that when I update the list with a new list that has the same element but a different position, my datastore will ignore the change because the value in the list doesn't change. Therefore, the data in the datastore doesn't change, and the latest element I add still remains in its original position instead of being added to the end of the list. I apologize for my poor English skills, so my question may not be clear, but I have done my best.

Comment: yeah, I see. let me try another solution then.

Comment: @HaBuiDuc try this solution and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: I have this error when using your code "Not enough information to infer type variable R"

Comment: can you specify the line of code where the error appears?

Comment: There are errors in line 8 and line 13 of your code. In line 8, there is an error that says "Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly." In line 13, there is an error that says "Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match."

Comment: I think the `List` type isn't enough to infer the type of the deserialized object, so I used `MutableList`. check it out @HaBuiDuc

Comment: I still have the same error. But I think the code that I provided in the question works fine. I just don't want to save to the data store twice and learn how to optimize my code, so I think I will keep my code. Thank you very much for your help. You have made my day.